# How to construct an HTTP GET request to filter a JSON response?

Tags: json, rest, curl

I'm making the following HTTP GET request with Curl:

curl http://rest.ensembl.org/variation/human/rs56116432?content-type=application

It returns the following JSON object:

```
{"source":"Variants (including SNPs and indels) imported from dbSNP","mappings":[{"location":"9:133256042-133256042","assembly_name":"GRCh38","end":133256042,"seq_region_name":"9","strand":1,"coord_system":"chromosome","allele_string":"C/T","start":133256042},{"location":"CHR_HG2030_PATCH:133256189-133256189","assembly_name":"GRCh38","end":133256189,"seq_region_name":"CHR_HG2030_PATCH","strand":-1,"coord_system":"chromosome","allele_string":"C/T","start":133256189}],"name":"rs56116432","MAF":"0.00259585","ambiguity":"Y","var_class":"SNP","synonyms":[],"evidence":["Multiple_observations","Frequency","1000Genomes","ESP","ExAC"],"ancestral_allele":"C","minor_allele":"T","most_severe_consequence":"missense_variant"
```

Is it possible to construct the HTTP request so that only the value of the key `"most_severe_consequence"` is returned to the browser instead of filtering the data after the request has been returned?

The APIs [documentation](http://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/variation_id) does not contain a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query parameter for which components of the response are desired.

e.g. http://rest.ensembl.org/variation/human/rs56116432?content-type=application;bit_i_care_about=most_severe_consequence

Alternatively, you could have an extra path element if you know you'll only ever want one field....

http://rest.ensembl.org/variation/human/rs56116432/most_severe_consequence?content-type=application

Comment: You seem to be suggesting ways that the service *could* do what the OP is asking and not ways which it actually supports.